# Disable touchscreen on x1 carbon when closed

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, touchscreen

I like to use my x1 carbon with the lid closed, and plugged into an external monitor. The problem is, the touchscreen misbehaves, causing weird tracking issues with the usb mouse (the cursor jumps about).

I edited  /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf as such:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

That solved my issue when working with the external monitor, but when I used my laptop later without the external monitor, the trackpad wasn't working.

Does anybody know how to disable the touchscreen but keep the trackpad functional?

Here are the entire contents of the file (without the `"Ignore"` option).

```
#
# Catch-all evdev loader for udev-based systems
# We don't simply match on any device since that also adds accelerometers
# and other devices that we don't really want to use. The list below
# matches everything but joysticks.

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```